# Universal Wiki Converter building with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, converters, wiki, universal

I am trying to build the uwc via Eclipse. I installed the Ant plugin to Eclipse. I used JRE 1.7 and 1.6, but in both cases I have no success. I get the following errors.
Did anyone experience with this tool?

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\****\workspace\UWCbuild\appfusions-universal-wiki-converter-cc46cdb17c5c\build.xml
    init:
    compile.module.uwc.production:
    [javac2] C:\Users\*****\workspace\UWCbuild\appfusions-universal-wiki-converter-cc46cdb17c5c\build.xml:156: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac2] Compiling 62 source files to C:\Users\******\workspace\UWCbuild\appfusions-universal-wiki-converter-cc46cdb17c5c\target\uwc\classes
    [javac2] C:\Users\******\workspace\UWCbuild\appfusions-universal-wiki-converter-cc46cdb17c5c\src\com\atlassian\uwc\ui\FeedbackWindow.java:296: error: incompatible types
    [javac2]            method = (State.Type) methodObj;
    [javac2]                     ^
    [javac2]   required: java.awt.Window.Type
    [javac2]   found:    com.atlassian.uwc.ui.State.Type
    [javac2] C:\Users\******\workspace\UWCbuild\appfusions-universal-wiki-converter-cc46cdb17c5c\src\com\atlassian\uwc\ui\FeedbackWindow.java:321: error: incomparable types: java.awt.Window.Type and com.atlassian.uwc.ui.State.Type
    [javac2]        if (method == State.Type.NOTE) { 
    [javac2]                   ^
    [javac2] C:\Users\******\workspace\UWCbuild\appfusions-universal-wiki-converter-cc46cdb17c5c\src\com\atlassian\uwc\ui\FeedbackWindow.java:337: error: incomparable types: java.awt.Window.Type and com.atlassian.uwc.ui.State.Type
    [javac2]        if (method == State.Type.STEP) {
    [javac2]                   ^
    [javac2] C:\Users\******\workspace\UWCbuild\appfusions-universal-wiki-converter-cc46cdb17c5c\src\com\atlassian\uwc\ui\FeedbackWindow.java:341: error: incomparable types: java.awt.Window.Type and com.atlassian.uwc.ui.State.Type
    [javac2]        else if (method == State.Type.MAX) {
    [javac2]                        ^
    [javac2] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac2] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac2] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac2] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac2] 4 errors

    BUILD FAILED
    C:\Users\******\workspace\UWCbuild\appfusions-universal-wiki-converter-cc46cdb17c5c\build.xml:156: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    Total time: 2 seconds
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidPostill 
thx for the hint.
I am working with the version which is provided on bitbucket.org

Available at
https://bitbucket.org/appfusions/universal-wiki-converter/downloads

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**

Comment: @DavidPostill
this is the build file which I am running. In the zipped repository file, there is a file called build.xml. I am actually running this file on eclipse. The error comes out from a called Feedback file at the following states:
`  try {
   state = (State) stateObs;
   problem = CastProblem.NOT_TYPE; //state cast didn't fail; let's try methodObj. Used by ClassCastException catch block 
   method = (State.Type) methodObj;
  } catch (ClassCastException e) {`

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Do you have a newer repository that is patched?

Comment: Hi Sorin, no sorry. This tool was build from one person and she is not responding for free, only in paid consultation. I found an alternative way to solve my problem and did not even use this tool.

Answer (score 2):

We got the exact same errors building it via cmdline on a Linux machine - so it's not related to Eclipse.

We solved it - at least for us - by modifying src/com/atlassian/uwc/ui/FeedbackWindow.java, changing a few types and/or type casts.

The commented-out lines below are the original ones:

```
//import com.atlassian.uwc.ui.State.Type;
import com.atlassian.uwc.ui.State;
...

public void update(Observable stateObs, Object methodObj) {
    State state;
    //Type method;
    State.Type method;
    CastProblem problem = CastProblem.NOT_STATE;
    try {
        state = (State) stateObs;
        problem = CastProblem.NOT_TYPE; //state cast didn't fail; let's try methodObj. Used by ClassCastException catch block
        //method = (Type) methodObj;
        method = (State.Type) methodObj;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
...

//private void updateFeedbackTextArea(State state, Type method) {
private void updateFeedbackTextArea(State state, State.Type method) {
    //if ((State.Type) method == State.Type.NOTE) {
    if (method == State.Type.NOTE) {
...

//private synchronized void updateProgressBar(State state, Type method) {
private synchronized void updateProgressBar(State state, State.Type method) {
...
```